# How to prevent git task from showing diff when running with --diff?

Tags: ansible

When running `ansible-playbook` with [`--diff`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_checkmode.html#showing-differences-with-diff), it's not very useful to get pages of output for `git` tasks.

Is there a way to prevent showing diff for certain tasks, similar to [`check_mode`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_checkmode.html#enabling-or-disabling-check-mode-for-tasks) for `--check`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just `diff: no`.

```
- copy:
    content: new_value
    dest: /tmp/test.txt
  diff: no
```

This will not display diff when playbook called with `--diff` switch.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I couldn't find it easily from the docs.

Comment: AFAIK, no. But you can peek into the [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.4/lib/ansible/playbook/base.py#L161-L169).

Comment: Turns out I'm already using `diff: False` in some of my playbooks, heh. Thanks for the answer, it certainly works!

Comment: How does `diff` compare to `no_log`? I'm trying to decide which one to use.

Comment: @user1338062: Currently it's in the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task